Network mismatch
I am trying to send a transaction on devnet network but for some reason I keep getting the error "Network mismatch
Your current network is set to Devnet, but this transaction is for Mainnet. Switch to the correct network before signing."
this is how I poison the transaction.
 const [txAmmount, setTx] = React.useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = React.useState("");
    const onChange = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setTx(target.value);
    const onChangeAddr = ({ target }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setAddress(target.value);
    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();



    const [txSig, setTxSig] = React.useState('');

    const link = () => {
        return txSig ? `https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSig}?cluster=devnet` : ''
    }

    const sendSol = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (!publicKey || !connection) { return };
        const transaction = new web3.Transaction();
        const reciverPubkey = new web3.PublicKey(address);

        console.log(connection)


        const transfer = web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: publicKey,
            toPubkey: reciverPubkey,
            lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * parseFloat(txAmmount)
        })

        transaction.add(transfer);
        sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
            .then((sig) => setTxSig(sig))
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
        const a = event

    }

this is where I hand over the enpoint and the wallet.
const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => web3.clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);
    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new walletAdapterWallets.SolflareWalletAdapter(),
        ],
        []
    );

    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    {children}
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};



It's hard to tell what's going on from this code, but be sure that the connection created by useConnection() is attached to devnet, and not mainnet

Same here, I bet useConnection() defaults to something other than devnet.

Same problem here. I confirm that the rpc is https://api.devnet.solana.com.
By printing the connection I can see it is the endpoint, yet solfare still saying me the tx is for mainnet. Moreover, if i change to mainnet, i got the opposite error: the current network is mainnet but this tx is for devnet.  WTF??

I had the same issue with Solflare on devnet. It was just fine with other wallets like Phantom if that helps. @Francesco
